# Не отдаётся хидер Last-Modified на php-fpm+nginx+http2

Tags: php

Этот файл не желает отдавать хидер с ласт-модифид
https://www.w3strict.ru/tlm.php
Содержимое файла

```
<?php
header("Last-Modified: Wed, 15 Nov 1995 04:58:08 GMT");
```

Файл без BOM, если попробовать отдать любой другой хидер, то удачно отдаётся (тот-же редирект). сервер - nginx+php-fpm.

Comment: Отдаваемый хедер в студию

Comment: ну, кроме этого хидера, нужно отдавать еще и другие. к тому же, на сервере может не проходить. вот [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/109043/) доходчиво

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо. Был включён SSI, который не позволяет отдать данный заголовок.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу Алекс-Арт от 30 окт в 21:05:

### Можно воспользоваться директивой `ssi_last_modified` со значением `on`

---

Синтаксис:  ssi_last_modified on | off;
Умолчание:  ssi_last_modified off;
Контекст:   http, server, location
Эта директива появилась в версии 1.5.1.
Позволяет сохранить поле заголовка “Last-Modified” исходного ответа во время обработки SSI для лучшего кэширования ответов.

По умолчанию поле заголовка удаляется, так как содержимое ответа изменяется во время обработки и может содержать динамически созданные элементы или части, которые изменились независимо от исходного ответа.

Источник: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_ssi_module.html